# Best practice: passing objects between Android activities

Tags: android, user-interface

I was wondering what the best practice is to pass objects between activies?
My logged out user is on a content item and should be able to get back to this item after the login process. Therefore I need to pass the content id between these activities

I see 2 basic options:

1. Pass the content-id in the intent as URI (intent.putExtra()) and pass them between activities
2. Save the content-id to the local storage and load it again after login

Are there any other options and best practices?

Comment: Of the two options you mention, passing the id as an Intent extra has the advantage that Android automatically keeps track of it over application background/resume and cleans it up when the activity finishes.

Comment: What kind of `Object` are you talking about? Do you already persist it somewhere? You should avoid sending complex `Objects` with `Intents`.

Comment: Best would be to pass the complex content-object, to reduce the server requests, but its also possible to store just the id and load the item again.

Comment: Do you have an office full of monkeys upvoting your question? (I think it's a bit off-topic)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i would suggest using [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html) which is like the option 2.
which allows your to get the content-id(or string or json object) after the app is closed.
you can also encrypt the content-id before put it in sharedPreferences

Besides intent (ram) and local storage (rom/sdcard , including database), i cant see any other option(locally).

> Case 1: you need to resume activity after the app is closed
>   you should use local storage
>
> Case 2: you don't need to resume activity
>   after the app is closed
>
> ```
> option 1:
>   0. load the first activity
>   1. start login_activity (startActivityForResult()) (do not call finish() )
>   2. after login is done (call finish())
>   3. activity is resumed (if login fail -> redirect to other activity )
>
> option 2:
>   1. create a public class with a data member to save the content-id/activity class
>      (you may assign singleton design pattern)
> ```

Comment: I'm already using SharedPreferences to store the login data. But I was thinking if it would not get to complex if every activity in the future will "misuse" this store.

Comment: i see your point,in my opinion, if there are IOS app/website along with the android app, server should take the responsibility.
but in this case,i think it depends on the amount of data you would like to cache. If there are tons of data, we will definitely use database, but if there is only one string(content-id),i dont think the store is "misused".

Comment: Loading the content is fine. 
But another point with the SharedPreferences is: how do you cleanup the store if the user doesn't complete the login? Isn't it very complex to react on every app-close, app-back etc. ?

Comment: to clean up the store, you can make reference to "when/how my cookies in browser being deleted", which has a time limit (say 5days).
i am sorry what do you mean `the user doesn't complete the login` ?
on every activity/content-id changes  (after login), you can override/append "lastContentId" in the local storage

Comment: I have the following workflow:

Contentdetail Activity (set id) 
=> Onboarding Activity => Login Activity => Base Activity (load id) =[inject id]=> Contentdetail Activity

I would have to react on every onAttachedToWindow when the user is closing the app during onboarding login and base activity

Comment: Option 2 works like a charm and is easy to use. Thank you.
I added a put(id) and getAndClear() method, which allows me to delete the contents as soon as it is queried to ensure its throws errors instead of having sideeffects.

In Scala it looks like that:

`class TransferObject[T] {

  @volatile
  private var transferItem: Option[T] = None

  def put(item: T) = {
    transferItem = Some(item)
  }

  def getAndClear: Option[T] = {
    val item = transferItem
    transferItem = None
    item
  }
}`